# Querying a SQL Server CE database offline using JOINs when using Microsoft Sync framework

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-ce, microsoft-sync-framework

I am getting this error when running my application, built using the sync framework, OFFLINE

> *The ntext and image data types cannot be used in WHERE, HAVING, GROUP
>   BY, ON, or IN clauses, except when these data types are used with the
>   LIKE or IS NULL predicates.*

I have a database holding some tests, TestOptions. Another holding test collections called CreateScript. These tables are used to populate a list view with tests to be carried out.

Using the Sync framework these tables have been cloned locally as SQL Server CE tables.

The user selects the desired test and the result is stored in the results table.

When populating the list view a query is run using two joins incorporating all three of these tables to gather the data for tests.

```
select 
    TestType, TestName, LowerLimits, UpperLimits 
from 
    CreateScriptTable 
inner join 
    TestOptionsTable on CreateScriptTable.TestType = TestOptionsTable.TestName 
LEFT JOIN 
    TestResultsTable on CreateScriptTable.TestType = TestResultsTable.TestName 
WHERE 
    CreateScriptTable.InstrumentType= 'type1' 
ORDER BY 
    [Index] ASC
```

This query works fine when the application is **online**. When the application is **offline** I get the exception above about the `nText` and `image` datatypes.

I also get the exception,

> *Large objects (ntext and image) cannot be used in ORDER BY clauses.*

when running a similar query to the one above.

In my database there are no column with these datatypes. From reading around it seems that the `varbinary(MAX)` and `nvarchar(MAX)` datatypes are cast to `image` and `nText` respectively on the local SQL Server CE database. To fix this I changed the datatypes to `nvarchar(4000)` and `varbinary(4000)` but the problem still persists.

There is a hot fix available [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/958478#appliesto) but it pre-dates the version SQL Server CE that is on my machine. I have not tested it yet as I am wary of messing up my development environment and am very close to needing a full build to demo.

I also toyed with the idea of creating in memory `DataTables` for each table and querying those but this has not worked out either.

At the moment I am out of ideas and would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ORDER BY CAST ([Index] as nvarchar(4000))
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That may fix the sorting issue but I still get the exception: *The ntext and image data types cannot be used in WHERE, HAVING, GROUP BY, ON, or IN clauses, except when these data types are used with the LIKE or IS NULL predicates.* It is odd as the Schema has been change on both client and server to ensure there are no nvarchar(MAX) datatypes.